# Best practices to avoid forgetting using var to declare variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

Javascript does not throw up errors when I forget to use var to declare a variable. Much time was lost debugging because of careless mistakes like these.

What are the best practices to avoid forgetting using var to declare variable in Javascript?

I hope Stack Overflow users do not close this question too soon or downvote it too much since there is no definite answer. It is a problem that is affecting newbies like me.

Comment: using [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/). Unfortunately there isn't a single opinion on that so this question is _still_ likely to get closed.

Comment: I'm using reSharper in Visual studio that is helps. Otherwise you can use http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: Also, there are errors on the console, if you're using Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Your question is like "How not to forget a language?", the answer is "Just speak it!", write code and use static analysis tools.

Comment: Perl has `use strict;` to do exactly this. Javascript also has `use strict;` but I think it does something else.

Comment: Missing var is not always a mistake, Javascript actually declares variables with or without using var keyword, the difference comes in their scope, read this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-in-ecmascript-262-3rd-edition-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `"use strict"` to the top of your js files. This will make it impossible to accidentally declare global variables. e.g.

```
"use strict";
mistypedVaraible = 17; // throws a ReferenceError
```

More detail is available on the mozilla developer network - [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode)

Linting tools such as [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/) / [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) would also go some way to checking the quality of your code. You could even use a task runner such as [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) (or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [Broccoli](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli), etc) to automate the process, so that your code is checked every time it is changed.

The [Sample Gruntfile](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile) walks you through an example which would watch, jshint, and concatinate your final build file (amongst other things)